# Spring Autowired and parallelStreams

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

How do I get @Autowired annotations to work in threads created by .parallelStream() in a spring REST request context?

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @GetMapping(value = "getStrings")
    public List<String> getAllStrings(List<String> request) {
        return request.parallelStream()
                .map(requestItem -> service.getString(requestItem))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

```
@Service
public class Service {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

    public String getString(String request) {
        // some code that uses resttemplate and httpheaders here, returns string
        // assume this request takes 2 sec to complete hence the need to make multiple calls in parallel
    }
}
```

The error I receive when actually running this code is

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.httpHeaders': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

One way around this issue is to pass the httpHeaders as an argument into getString() but that would require a bunch of refactoring for every other class that uses that method

I've found that parallelStreams can use a custom thread pool, but have no clue on how to get the current thread pool that the spring request context uses (or if reusing the same thread pool even solves my problem)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding

```
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

on your service.